# Struts 2 s:if Vs struts 1 logic:notEqual - null handling

Tags: struts2

The following struts 1 code evaluates to true when row.type is null.

```
<logic:notEqual property="type" name="row" value="head">
```

The same I converted into struts2 as below but it evaluates to false when row.type is null.

```
<s:if test='%{! #row.type.equals("head")}'>
```

How to make this true when #row.type is null.

Tried as below still not working.

```
<s:if test="%{#row.type != null}">
   // Control Not going inside
</s:if>
<s:if test='%{(! #row.type.equals("head") ) || #row.type == null}'>
   // here also not going inside
</s:if>
```

Comment: `row` can be null.

Comment: no it's not. I;m able to get other fields like, #row.name

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<s:if test='%{! "head".equals(#row.type)}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parentheses helped.

```
<s:if test='%{ ! ("head".equals(#row.type)) }'>
```